# Why does multiplying a double by -1 not give the negative of the current answer

Tags: java, double, multiplication, negative-number

I am trying to multiply a double value by -1 to get the negative value. It continues to give me a positive value

**EDIT:** I am putting all the code up.

public class DecToTime {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    DecToTime dtt = new DecToTime();    
    double val = dtt.getNumber("13.930000000000E+02");
    System.out.println(val);

  }

public double getNumber(String number) throws IOException{

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(number);
    int c;
    String mantissa="";
    String sign="";
    String exponent="";
    boolean isMantissa=true;

    while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        char character = (char) c;
      if(character=='E'){
          isMantissa=false;  
      }
      if(isMantissa==true){
          mantissa=mantissa+character;
      }

      if(isMantissa==false){
          if((character=='+')|| (character=='-')){
              if(character=='+') {
                  sign = "plus";
              }
              if(character=='-') {
                  sign = "minus";
              }
          }
          if(!(sign.equals(""))){
              exponent=exponent+character;
          }
      }

    }
    System.out.println(mantissa+" - "+sign+" - "+exponent);
    double man = Double.parseDouble(mantissa);
    double exp;
    if(sign.equals("plus")){
        exp = Double.parseDouble(exponent);
    }
    else {
        exp = Double.parseDouble(exponent);
System.out.println("Exp: "+exponent);
    }   
    System.out.println(man+" - "+sign+" - "+exp);
    double value = man*Math.pow(10, exp);
    return value;
}
```

}

The printed result is

> 13.93 - minus - 2.0

which is correct except that 2.0 should be -2.0

Comment: The other code works fine, so I haven't included it as it would just be unecessary.

Comment: Are you sure "else" is ever hit?

Comment: What does System.out.println("|"+exponent+"|"); show?

Comment: Sorry to be radical here, but have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: @James B Why, isn't stackoverflow.com a debugger? :-o ;-)

Comment: Stating the obvious, why can't you just say 'exp = -Double.parseDouble(exponent)' in the else case. I agree with Péter Török about the source of the problem though.

Comment: Thanks, well really I just wanted to confirm that you could multiply doubles by -1 to get a negative value. Of course logically you must be able to for some reason I was wondering if you needed to do something else  ..... headache. Obviously it's just a silly bug and not a real programming question.

Comment: @Agnel Kurian - that seems like a good idea. I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that in the `else` branch, the parsed value of `exp` is already negative, so negating it results in the positive value you see. Try printing out its value *before* the negation.

It would certainly help us (and you) if you showed / printed the original value of `exponent` though.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the multiplication decision on the sign string. so it would help if you would include more code. showing how sign is being set up

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your problem, both the code and the output look ok to me.

I'd add a debugging statement ("System.out.println(exp)") before the multiplication to better understand if the program behaviour is right.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in a method and add a unit test with your assertions - does it pass or fail?

Also DRY - you might as well parse the exponent before the if statement since you do it in both branches anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It gives correct result. I guess the value of `exponent` parses to negative.

Answer (score 0):

Exponent can be negative. It is for numbers smaller than 1.

What you want to multiply is the mantissa. That's what controls the sign of the whole number.

```
-0.02 = -1 * 2 * 10^(-2) = sign * mantissa * base ^ exp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, and it executed as expected with mantissa = "2.66", and sign="negate".
Try debugging into it if you're still facing problems. Also check to see the .class is not being cached someplace .... I've known that to happen, and cause weird problems.